# Getting clientID and clientSecret for live paypal account

Tags: java, paypal, integration, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I have successfully tested my application on paypal `sandbox` account. Now I want to use my real account on my application. The problem is I am not able to get the `clientId` and `clientSecret` for live account. I went through paypal documents and have got `API Username`, `API Password` and `Signature` like shown in the image below from [here](https://www.paypal.com/np/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-api-signature#):-

[image]

I want to know whether these are the real username and password which I need for real account (live account) or I will need `clientID` and `clientSecret` for the same. If I need `clientId` and `clientSecret` then how would I be able to get that.

Thank you

UPDATE :-
Okay after going through paypal documents, I found a `sandbox` and `live` option to get the app credentials as :-

[image]

As this is my business account, Here I got 2 types of credentials a `sandbox` environment and a `live` credential. Is this the actual `live` credential that I need for my live paypal account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating an application with PayPal, you can't just simply copy and paste API keys/passwords/etc. There's a process to it when you're outside of sandbox.

Navigate to the My Apps & Credentials page, and log in if necessary. In the REST API Apps section, click Create App to begin the application-creation process. For details about how to create and manage your PayPal applications, see Manage your applications.

When you create an app, PayPal generates a set of OAuth keys for the application (the keys consist of a client_id and secret). These keys are created for both the Sandbox and Live environments.

My Apps & Credentials Page Link: https://www.paypal-apps.com/user/my-account/applications

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thank you for the information. I have found a `live` option from paypal's developer site which you can see in my updated question. Is the the ultimate `clientId` and `clientSecret` that I need? I haven't shown the secret though

Comment: https://www.paypal-apps.com/user/my-account/applications

This link is giving "502 Bad Gateway" error.  Can you please suggest anything else to work it out?